# Chosen jquery dropdown options does not remains open when clicking on dropdown in IE8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, jquery-chosen

I am using chosen.js plugin for multi selection dropdown in IE8. When I clicks on dropdown for selecting a option a option list opens below the dropdown. On mouse up, it disapperar and I am not able to select it. It should remain open.

**Update**

This is my code for dropdown list:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ddlSegRequirement" runat="server" class="chosen" Style="width: 500px" SelectionMode="Multiple" data-placeholder="Select...">
<asp:ListItem Value="1">Logical segregation</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2">Physical segregation</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="3">Other</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

and in jquery

```
$(".chosen").chosen();
```

Comment: Can you provide some code and/or and example? Please see: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Use [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/). It is based on Chosen and is more widely used than Chosen itself. And Do not code for IE8. [World has moved on (almost)](http://theie8countdown.com/)